# How to know fetch JSON data from server is object or string?

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting JSON data from server, I have always confusion about this, How I will know that, fetched data is json string or json object. I have asked two questions but both are related.

```
{"series": [{"meter": "instance", "data": [{"y": 82.0, "x": "2015-07-14T23:58:00"}, {"y": 142.0, "x": "2015-07-15T23:58:10"}, {"y": 144.0, "x": "2015-07-16T23:58:10"}, {"y": 139.0, "x": "2015-07-17T23:56:17"}, {"y": 144.0, "x": "2015-07-18T23:56:18"}, {"y": 144.0, "x": "2015-07-19T23:56:17"}, {"y": 277.0, "x": "2015-07-20T23:50:09"}, {"y": 294.0, "x": "2015-07-21T23:51:34"}, {"y": 135.0, "x": "2015-07-22T07:21:34"}], "name": "demo", "unit": "instance"}], "settings": {}}
```

If above is JSON object or JSON string then how will I convert into each other?

Comment: you can check with typeof. to find the type of response/variable

Comment: May be this helps you - **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)**

Comment: A web server cannot serve JSON _objects_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check the response header `content-type: application/json` which will give what content type it is.

string to json-> `JSON.parse(str);`
json to String -> `JSON.stringify(jsonObj);`

Comment: thanks for the `content-type: application/json` I is showing like Content-Type=application/json, But Is is json object or Json string...

Comment: if content type is application/json then it is an json object. for string it would be text/html

Answer (score 1):

HTTP can only work with string type data in fact, and you need to format the responsed data string according to the http response header which the field name is `Content-Type`, and json value is `application/json`.

That means, the value is always a string, but there's another variable(Content-Type) to record it's type format.